# How to make a function accept certain parameters using templates and concepts

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to write a function that accepts a certain number of parameters using constant templates, for example:

```cpp
template<int count>
void foo(int... args) { ... }

foo<1>(0); // success
foo<2>(0); // error
foo<3>(0, 0, 0); // success
```

`count` in templates decides how many parameters it can accept.

I tried to write a prototype like this

```cpp
template <int a, int b>
concept equal = (a == b);

template <int size>
void foo(int... args) requires equal<sizeof...(args), size>
{ ... }
```

and it fails to complie.
What is the correct way to do it, or is there a simplier method.

thanks very much

Comment: Always include error in your post, always.

Comment: Using `std::array` or `std::intializer_list` might be a good alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int... args` is not the way to have `int arg0, int arg1, .., int argN`

`int...` is used for `number0, number1, ..., numberN`
as in [`std::integer_sequence<int, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

You might do:

```
template<int count, std::same_as<int> ...Ints>
void foo(Ints... args) requires (sizeof...(args) == count)
{
  // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oKfvPsbrW)

Comment: It works well. Thank you. Does it means you cant use basic types instead of template typenames in variable parameters?

Comment: There is [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1219r1.html) to allow your syntax (or similar).

Answer (score 3):

##### C++ 17

You can also use [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) as shown below. This way you can also use it in c++11 or c++17:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int size, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<int, Args> && ... && (sizeof...(Args)==size))> foo(Args... args) 
{  }
```

##### C++20

```
#include <type_traits>
template <int a, int b>
concept equal = (a == b);

template <int size, typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) requires (std::is_same_v<int, Args> && ... && equal<sizeof...(Args), size> )
{  }
int main() {
  
foo<1>(0); // success
//foo<2>(0); // error 
foo<3>(0, 0, 0); // success  
  
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8YK67GEcP)